# Using single delay in LED blinking

Tags: msp430

The following code basically blinks yellow  [LED on MSP430 Launch Pad](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C335/HTML/msp430GetStarted.HTM) on port 1.6.

I had to use two

> do-while

loops for providing delays. Is there a way I can do this using a single do-while ?

```
int main(void)
{
      P2DIR = 0xFF;
      P2OUT = 0x00;
          P3DIR = 0xFF;
          P3OUT = 0x00;
        volatile unsigned int i;    // volatile to prevent optimization
       WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;       // Stop watchdog timer
       P1DIR |= 0x40;                  // Set P1.6 (Green LED) to output
       while( 1 ) {
           i = 9000;                    // SW Delay
           do i--;
               while(i != 0);
           P1OUT |= 0x40;              // Green LED On
           i = 9000;                    // SW Delay
             do i--;
       while(i != 0);

       P1OUT &= ~0x40;             // Green LED Off
   }
}
```

Comment: Loop at the Sleep() or Delay() methods. (depending on which is available)

Comment: @Psychic - this is an MSP430, so that would be neither Sleep() nor Delay().

Comment: @Psychic For which controllers Sleep() and Delay() routines are available?

Comment: For the MSP430 take a look at __delay_cycles(). Not time based, but still a means of putting in a delay. For other chips, like the AVR's or the PICs, most support Sleep/Delay in some fashion. eg http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/delay

Comment: @gpuguy No Controller... It's generally, OS's/Compiler's feature or you have to write it on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to blink the LED, you can use X-OR rather than & and OR
so, it will be like:

```
 while( 1 )
   {
           i = 9000;                    // SW Delay
           do 
           {
              i--;
           } while(i != 0);
           P1OUT ^= 0x40;              // Toggle Green LED
    }
```

XOR is normally used for Toggling.

Comment: This sort of delay should be implemented with one of the hardware timer channels and a timer interrupt, allowing the processor to go away and do something useful.

Comment: @Ian I agree but OP asked about Blinking with one "do-while" so....